# Adding a mapped drive with WNetAddConnection2 is not accessible

Tags: network-programming, drive-mapping

I'm trying to map a drive using `WNetAddCOnnection2` but there's something not quite right.  The code that I am using from [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/mpr/WNetAddConnection2.html) and seems to work at first.  If I am stepping through the code I get a 0 for a response and I am able to use `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles()` to inspect the new mapped drive which leads me to believe that credentials are fine.

The problem is that the drive is not available outside of the application.  When I type `net use` from a command prompt I see the drive listed like this:

```
Unavailable  L:        \\<server>\<share>          Microsoft Windows Network
```

When I try to access the drive I get either:

```
The system cannot find the drive specified.
```

or

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the nutshell of the code in question:

```
NETRESOURCE res = new NETRESOURCE();
res.iScope = RESOURCE_GLOBALNET;
res.iType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
res.iDisplayType = RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SHARE;
res.iUsage = RESOURCEUSAGE_CONNECTABLE;
res.sRemoteName = share;
res.sLocalName = drive;
res.sProvider = null;

int iFlags = 0;
iFlags = CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE;

int iResult = WNetAddConnection2( ref res, psPassword, psUsername, iFlags );
```

The `iResult` always ends up equaling 0.

Answer (score 1):

**MSDN articles that may assist:**
* WNetAddConnection2 - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385413%28VS.85%29.aspx][1] 
* NETRESOURCE - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385353%28VS.85%29.aspx][2]

I reckon your problem is the display type where "res.iDisplayType = RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SHARE". Perhaps try changing to a value of "0" (RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_GENERIC). So for example, what I generally use to map drives appears:

---

```
With Res  
  .dwScope = RES_SCOPE_GLOBALNET 'value 2  
  .dwType = RES_TYPE_DISK 'value of 1  
  .dwUsage = RES_USE_CONNECT 'value of 1  
  .localName = "x:" 'leave blank for no drive   
  .RemoteName = "\\\"  
End With 
lRes = WNetAddConnection2(Res, sPassword, sDomain & "\" & sPassword, RES_CNN_UPDATE_PROFILE) 
If lRes = 0 Then
  'Success 
Else   
  'Error 
End If
```

---

Always check your connections before & after calls from command prompt:

1a) From system making connection, list current connections:

```
   net use
```

1b) From system connected too, list current sessions:

```
   net session
```

To disconnect session, use API 'WNetCancelConnection2', my code following from above:

---

```
sServer = "\\\"
lRes = WNetCancelConnection2(sServer, RES_CNN_UPDATE_PROFILE, True)
If lRes `> 0 Then 
  'Success
Else
  'Error
End If
```

---

Alternatively, simply making connections using 'net' command:

1) To map a drive letter:

```
  net use `: \\`\` /user:`\` `
```

2) To map an IPC connection:

```
  net use \\`\` /user:`\` `
```

Disconnecting using 'net' command:

1) Disconnecting mapped drive:

```
  net use `: /delete
```

2) Disconnecting server share:

```
  net use \\`\` /delete
```